# Wix installer detected as malware by browsers, windows smartscreen and antivirus software

Tags: wix, certificate

So I'm trying to sell my first (personal) software product online ([shameless plug](http://www.thingiequery.com)). It's a VSTO Excel plugin which I'm having trouble distributing. I've made a (wix bootstrap) installer and hosted it on the project website. While my product might not be fantabulous, I'm pretty sure it's not malware. However when people download it the following software seems to think otherwise:

1. Browsers
2. Windows 8 (SmartScreen)
3. Antivirus software

The browsers warn the user that the .exe could be dangerous as it's not often downloaded, Windows SmartScreen warns the user that the installer might be dangerous and advises the user not to install it, antivirus software sees the dlls (the ones that are obfuscated) as threats.

I don't think many people will install my software with all these warnings. My question is: How does a 1-man software start-up distribute software with all these roadblocks?

Would buying an EV certificate solve all of the above problems? Can I use such a certificate to sign my wix bootstrap installer?

Also, if I use a normal (non EV) authenticode certificate to sign my files and installer, how long could it take to build up enough reputation to satisfy SmartScreen? I know it probably depends, but I'd like to hear peoples experiences with this.

Comment: It's normal for Windows to complain about non-certificate-signed code from the internet. That might solve the first two issues. I've been doing MSI installs for a long time and I never heard of a Dll being flagged as potential AV issues. The more normal issue is attempting to update registry Run or RunOnce keys. So more detail might be needed about the AV product and its false positives and what is in your code that causes them. Is it possible that the Dlls have actually been compromised? Don't overlook that.

Comment: Phil, thanks for the answer. The AV is Symantec Endpoint Protection, it classifies the obfuscated files as "Suspicious.Cloud.5". Their website says that means: "...designed to detect entirely new malware threats without traditional signatures...". I'll try without obfuscation and see what happens.

Comment: That sounds like marketing speak for a heuristic scan of things that might be dangerous, rather than the traditional match of a known threat. I don't know what obfuscation would product that looks dangerous, but if they are going to flag a lot of obfuscated code they will get a lot of complaints. I'd report it to them, and are there other obfuscation algorithms that you could use?

Comment: And Symantec sells EV certs.  How about that....  Myself and a few customers have been in your boat. I maintain an small open source project that gets flagged with each new release since I have so few downloads and I refuse to jump through the hoops to keep renewing my cert like I've done in years gone by.  I'd just put up a good FAQ page on it and move on.